# why no image displayed on the left page

Tags: html, image

I have [this page](http://test2.tamarawobben.nl/nl-NL/foreword.html).

On the left of the page there's meant be a image displayed but as you can see no image.
I know for sure the image's URL is correct.

Can anyone help me figure out why the image is not displayed?

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is correct, however you have a typo.

You've written `<img scr="....` instead of `<img src="...`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is off with your image path. Try using `/css/images/tamara.jpg` instead of `../css/images/tamara.jpg`. If that doesn't work, try the full URL to the image.

Best,

Cynthia

Answer (score 1):

Use

`<img src="css/images/filename.jpg">`

instead of

`<img src="..css/images/filename.jpg">`